# "The usage of semaphores is subtly wrong"

Tags: c, concurrency, semaphore, producer-consumer

This past semester I was taking an OS practicum in C, in which the first project involved making a threads package, then writing a multiple producer-consumer program to demonstrate the functionality. However, after getting grading feedback, I lost points for "The usage of semaphores is subtly wrong" and "The program assumes preemption (e.g. uses yield to change control)" (We started with a non-preemptive threads package then added preemption later. Note that the comment and example contradict each other. I believe it doesn't assume either, and would work in both environments).

This has been bugging me for a long time - the course staff was kind of overwhelmed, so I couldn't ask them what's wrong with this over the semester. I've spent a long time thinking about this and I can't see the issues. If anyone could take a look and point out the error, or reassure me that there actually isn't a problem, I'd really appreciate it.

I believe the syntax should be pretty standard in terms of the thread package functions (minithreads and semaphores), but let me know if anything is confusing.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "minithread.h"
#include "synch.h"
#define BUFFER_SIZE 16
#define MAXCOUNT 100

int buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
int size, head, tail;
int count = 1;
int out = 0;
int toadd = 0;
int toremove = 0;

semaphore_t empty;
semaphore_t full;
semaphore_t count_lock; // Semaphore to keep a lock on the 
                        // global variables for maintaining the counts


/* Method to handle the working of a student 
    * The ID of a student is the corresponding minithread_id */
int student(int total_burgers) {
    int n, i;
    semaphore_P(count_lock);
    while ((out+toremove) < arg) {
        n = genintrand(BUFFER_SIZE);
        n = (n <= total_burgers - (out + toremove)) ? n : total_burgers - (out + toremove);
        printf("Student %d wants to get %d burgers ...\n", minithread_id(), n);
        toremove += n;
        semaphore_V(count_lock);
        for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
            semaphore_P(empty);
            out = buffer[tail];
            printf("Student %d is taking burger %d.\n", minithread_id(), out);
            tail = (tail + 1) % BUFFER_SIZE;
            size--;
            toremove--;
            semaphore_V(full);
        }
        semaphore_P(count_lock);
    }
    semaphore_V(count_lock);
    printf("Student %d is done.\n", minithread_id());
    return 0;
}

/* Method to handle the working of a cook 
    * The ID of a cook is the corresponding minithread_id */
int cook(int total_burgers) {
    int n, i;
    printf("Creating Cook %d\n",minithread_id());
    semaphore_P(count_lock);
    while ((count+toadd) <= arg) {
        n = genintrand(BUFFER_SIZE);
        n = (n <= total_burgers - (count + toadd) + 1) ? n : total_burgers - (count + toadd) + 1;
        printf("Cook %d wants to put %d burgers into the burger stack ...\n", minithread_id(),n);
        toadd += n;
        semaphore_V(count_lock);
        for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
            semaphore_P(full);
            printf("Cook %d is putting burger %d into the burger stack.\n", minithread_id(), count);
            buffer[head] = count++;
            head = (head + 1) % BUFFER_SIZE;
            size++;
            toadd--;
            semaphore_V(empty);
        }
        semaphore_P(count_lock);
    }
    semaphore_V(count_lock);
    printf("Cook %d is done.\n", minithread_id());
    return 0;
}

/* Method to create our multiple producers and consumers
    * and start their respective threads by fork */
void starter(int* c){
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<c[2];i++){
        minithread_fork(cook, c[0]);
    }
    for (i=0;i<c[1];i++){
        minithread_fork(student, c[0]);
    }
}


/* The arguments are passed as command line parameters
    * argv[1] is the no of students
    * argv[2] is the no of cooks */
void main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int pass_args[3];
    pass_args[0] = MAXCOUNT;
    pass_args[1] = atoi(argv[1]);
    pass_args[2] = atoi(argv[2]);

    size = head = tail = 0;
    empty = semaphore_create();
    semaphore_initialize(empty, 0);
    full = semaphore_create();
    semaphore_initialize(full, BUFFER_SIZE);
    count_lock = semaphore_create();
    semaphore_initialize(count_lock, 1);

    minithread_system_initialize(starter, pass_args);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your semaphores do nothing to protect buffer, head, etc in the innermost loop. One thread acquires sempahore "empty", the other acquires semaphore "full" while no other semaphores are held. This seems to guarantee eventual corruption.

Comment: I think I understand: so the solution would be to add another semaphore (or reuse count_lock), locking right before the line out = buffer[tail]; and releasing right after toremove--;, correct?

Comment: Actually... if you restructure your code (get rid of the global variables to the extent you can) you just need one semaphore to protect the buffer/size/head/tail variables.